# Check delivery availability depend on customer location

Tags: magento2, delivery

I'm developing a Magento 2 store, My client have several restaurants across the country and he wants to be sure that the customer is within the delivery range for his/her nearest store (5 km).

The customer should have a map to pin his address, if his is on the range he can place the order, otherwise a message will be displayed that he is out of the delivery zone.

I have found several modules that restricted the delivery but uses only zip codes to check the customer location. I need to do the exact same thing but by letting the customer pin his location on a map.

Here is an example of the functionality
https://www.mcdelivery.eg/eg/guest.html